# Cannot install NVIDIA graphics driver on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-nforce

I have an ASUS board (m4n68t-m le v2) with on board Nvidia graphics chipset model#: **nForce 630a/ GeForce 7025.** 
I have Windows 10 installed and I have now installed Ubuntu 19.10 on the same HDD having a dual boot scenario. The problem is i am not able to find and install the correct nvidia driver version on ubuntu.

I have to say I am fairly new to Linux, hence from various sources/forums, here is what I have done so far:

1. blacklisted default open source nouveau driver
2. ran update-initramfs -u after that
3. downloaded the compatible .run package from nvidia site and tried installing. every time there is a kernel error. tried all options - with/without DKMS etc.
4. tried installing using package manager using: sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx. Not able to connect to Nvidia driver error. Had to move back to nouveau.
5. Additional problems:
   a) ubuntu-drivers devices: returns nothing.
   b) from software & updates GUI - nothing appears in additional drivers tab (no recomended drivers etc.)
   c) lspci | grep VGA command shows the correct adapter information:
   00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 7025/ nForce630a] (rev a2)
6. Many forums say to disable Secure Boot or UEFI mode, but both options are missing from my BIOS. Its currently running in Legacy (MBR) mode.
7. Formatted the partitions and re-installed ubuntu but with no luck. ran: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y etc.. no use!

---

Kernel (uname -r) :5.3.0-24-generic
Ubuntu Version: 19.10

Have been trying to fix this for over a week now. With no resolution. So any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try installing *not from* Nvidia? eg: https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/nvidia-340

Comment: @A.B thanks for your response. No, I have not tried that yet. Could you please share the process ?.. never tried that before. Do I download the .deb package for amd- as my system is and install from the terminal ?

Comment: That was just a pointer not an answer. You use your package manager to ask for packages and it will retrieve what's needed. You should look on internet to know what package to get.

Comment: @A.B installing from the ubuntu site did NOT work.

Comment: it was worth a try. I wonder why ubuntu ships those nvidia binaries

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with a Qosmio Laptop with Nvidia-340. I think NVIDIA has stopped working on the driver. It stopped working in Ubuntu 19.10 and in Windows 10. My only solution was to disable Nouveau and enable nvidiafb. Set grub to load at whatever resolution you like. I use 1920x1200. It's slow to load and you can't use dual monitors but it does make the system usable.

I have been able to load the nvidia-340.108 driver but it doesn't work. If anyone has a better solution or have been able to fix the driver I'd appreciate seeing it.

Comment: I spoke to someone from Nvidia after trying everything. They said the chipset doesn’t support Ubuntu 18 and Windows 10. So not sure if any driver would properly work.